# Grails error: table or view does not exist

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When ever I start my Grails application, I get these errors for all my domain classes.

```
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table domain_class cascade constraints
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  -ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

and then

```
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  -ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I am using in-memory database for the application and my DataSource.groovy has this in it:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    local {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the settings in DataSource? 
I start my application with `grails -Dgrails.env=local run-app -https`

I tried to create objects during startup using BootStrap.groovy and even they fail. I use GGTS for development. What privileges is this talking about?

Comment: Add the full content of `DataSource.groovy` in the question. Here you are using `local` environment which is a custom environment. I doubt application would be referring to an Oracle db in `development` environment.

Comment: Updated. That is the command where I specifically tell it to use local environment. Is this useful?

Comment: nowhere Oracle db is referred in the DataSource. You should update the full content of DataSource.

Comment: Here is the whole Datasource. More info on errors added, if it helps.

Comment: It's confusing that you're getting an Oracle error code when using the H2 database.  One has to conclude that *something* is configured to use Oracle in your project.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to create objects in the bootstrap file?

Comment: I get `Error initializing the application: getGeneratedKeys() support is not enabled` when it is going for objects creation in bootstrap file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer. The `dataSource` in file `instanceConfig.local.properties` in the resources folder was pointing to an Oracle database and I am not configured to a role to create or drop tables there. Hence the insufficient privileges error.

Even though the `DataSource.groovy` had the in-memory database setting, I assume that the `instanceConfig.local.properties` overrides it. Thanks anyways for the help guys!