# Multiple domain objects creation in Grails

Tags: grails, domain-object

I would like to create around 30 domain objects inside a controller. Here is how I wrote for the first object and it works fine (can see the output on index.gsp). Now, if I have to do the same for the 30 objects I need, should I have 30 different names or is there a simpler way?

```
class VendorController {

    def index() {
        def myvendor = new Vendor(name: "myVendor")

        [vendor: vendor]
    }
```

I know I can create objects in the BootStrap.groovy, but that isn't working (check [Grails error: table or view does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285521/grails-error-table-or-view-does-not-exist?noredirect=1#comment46806716_29285521)) Until I figure out the mistake there, I want to create the objects in the controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in a service with a transaction, but that aside, you can do the following syntax:

```
(1..10).each { idx ->
  new Vendor(name: "myVendor_${idx}").save()
}
```